# Is there any limitation/ security risk by using App Group Directory compared to Application Support Directory to store all my app related data?

Tags: ios, swift

All the while, I am storing my app related data (images, audio files, zip files, ...) in Application Support Directory

```
static func getUserDataDirectory() -> URL {
    let fm = FileManager.default
    do {
        let userDataDirectory = try fm.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        return userDataDirectory
    } catch {
        print("\(error)")
    }
    
    fatalError()
}
```

---

One of the main reason I choose **Application Support Directory**, over **Document Directory** is that,

1. I do not want 3rd party app to access my app content.
2. I do not want user to access the app data manually, without going through my app.

Now, I want to create 2 extensions for my app

1. Share extension - So that user can share data from 3rd party app to my app.
2. Widget extension - So that user can have my app widget.

I plan to migrate all my current existing data in **Application Support Directory**, to **App Group Directory**, so that my extensions will have access to all app data.

```
static func getUserDataDirectory() -> URL {
    let fm = FileManager.default
    
    let userDataDirectory = fm.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.xxx.yyy")
    
    userDataDirectory
}
```

However, I was wondering, by doing so, is there any technical limitation, or security risk involved?

Will 3rd party app able to access my App Group Directory, or will user able to access my App Group Directory data without going through my app?

Thanks.

Comment: only other apps in your group which you control